# Moving from working prod Magento 2 install to local docker all white screens everywhere. No errors anywhere

Tags: magento2, migration, docker, opensource

We have a **working prod version** of Magento running at Nexcess. We are trying to debug an integration and want to get it running locally.

We've pulled down all the production files and db and have them running and communicating in our docker containers. The magento container is able to talk to the db and redis. I *think* elastic search is running properly.

We updated the urls in the config to point to localhost & 127.0.0.1 (Maybe this is the problem? But we couldn't seem to get it to work from the container IP)

We've been through the following sequence (and other similar) many times

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

We've put it into developer mode. We've tried everything in any vaguely related article. All of the errors are turned on. We know it's running the php engine. We have an info.php that loads fine.

It runs the site without issue, and we get no output. bootstrap.run does nothing.

There are no errors we can find anywhere. We've been at this for days now and have run out of leads to pull. Any ideas?